# How these phrases can be simplified?

Tags: concision

I often write technical texts and not being a native speaker I am facing difficulties to make introductory sentences (including this one) concise. I just scrolled through my manuscript and found these patterns repeat many times:

- The advantage here is that there are a number of reference results for ...
- What is even more appealing is that it can ...
- Unusual here is that this is ...

Can these intros be optimized somehow? Some extended example would be

Unusual here is that this is a matrix with small off-diagonal elements.

Comment: It would help if you provided complete sentences. You may receive some comments indicating that this site doesn't provide writing advice. I'm not sure yet though that that's what you're lookin for. *Concision* is a tag.

Comment: @RichardKayser Exactly, by providing full sentences will implicate that I am explicitly seeking for a "writing advice", which I am not. Here, I rather provide common patterns and hope to learn from the solutions. However, I will try to expand these patterns following your advice.

Comment: Advantageously, there are... ; Moreover, it can ... ; Unusually, this is ...

Comment: @Greybeard Amazing, these are simple suggestions, but they have alleviated my block! Why not putting them as an answer.

Comment: Do you need to point any of these things out? If your sentence is “Unusual here is that only one in ten thousand births is x” then there’s no reason to include any of the words before “only”.

Comment: Well, sometimes I need to indicate that something is unusual because it is not immediately clear from the context.

Comment: "Unusually, this matrix has small off-diagonal elements." Here you are replacing "Unusual here is that" with Unusually", and "this is a matrix with" by "this matrix has". To stick closer to your original intent, you could say, "This matrix is unusual in having small off-diagonal elements." This preserves your emphasis on the unusualness of the matrix. I prefer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lengthy phrases are adverbial and can be replaced by adverbs:

Advantageously, there are... ;

Moreover, it can ... ;

Unusually, this is ..

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the principal nouns as your subjects.

> Unusual here is that this is a matrix with small off-diagonal elements. --> This **matrix** is unusual in having small off-diagonal elements.
>
> The advantage here is that there are a number of reference results for … --> This **approach** (option, ...) has the advantage of having a number of reference results for …
>
> What is even more appealing is that it can … --> **It** has the even more appealing feature of ...